# .pem files and .p12 file and URL's - oh my

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-7, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having real issues attempting to contact a secure rest URL. Basically I have little knowledge of certificates, and am wondering whether what I am doing with the certificate file(s) is correct.

1. I have 2 URL's effectively one for read and one for write.
2. I have 2 .pem files, one for each, that were provided with the URLs. The act of importing these into Certificate manager didn't change the outcome below).
3. I have also a .p12 file, which if I'm honest don't know where it fits in to all this... (I cannot import this into my Win7 cert magager as I do not have a password)

When running req.GetResponse() an exception occurs:

```
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
Inner Ex: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."
```

I'm currently unsure as to whether things need a little tinkering or I'm simply way off.
code is basically...

```
if (!File.Exists(certificateLocation)) 
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("The specified certificate file does not exist: {0}", certificateLocation));
}

//Cert Challenge URL 
Uri requestURI = new Uri(url);

//Create the Request Object
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURI);

//Set the Request Object parameters
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

//Create certificate from our file
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificateLocation);
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse(); // *** Errors here

...
```

Edit: Currently I'm only attempting the "read" url - seemed logical.

After contacting the issuer for the password accompanying the .p12 certificate, and importing that into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities section" of certification manager, the error has now changed to the following...

```
System.Net.WebException
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
Inner Ex:
"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
```

Comment: Where did you get the p12 file? iirc, the password is created at the same time as the file.

Comment: Hi Robert, the p12 came from the issuer at the same time as the urls and pem files. Does the p12 get used in conjunction with the pem files? Can I do without the p12?

Comment: Bit rusty on this but, from my addled memory, I think you're gonna need that password.

Comment: Load the certificate's root certificate into your **local machine**'s certificates' "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store. I guess your importing didn't work as you did it for your current user, and the code runs as a different user.

Comment: I've loaded both .pem files in there to no avail.

Comment: In what store exactly did you import them and at what location? As which user does this code run? What does the Certificates MMC plugin say about the validity of this certificate?

Comment: In certmgr they are in [Certificates - Current User\Trusted Root Certification Authorities]. The app is a webform app so is also running as myself. The certs expire in the future intended Purposes <All>. Certificate Status on the Certification Path tab is "This certificate is OK."

Comment: @Robert you were right about the password. I've now been issued with a password, and imported the p12 cert - thanks. Updated the question with the new error.

Comment: p12 should be imported to CurrentUser\My store (based on the niformation that webapp runs under your personal account). If CA certificate was in .p12 file, then it should be moved to trusted root store.

Comment: If you don't want to use windows store to do this, you can try with  this code `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificateLocation, "password to .p12 file goes here");
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);`. See, I changed `X509Certificate` class with `X509Certificate2` class.

Comment: Thanks for the info pepo. Interestingly, when you add the cert via the X509Certificate2 method but enter an incorrect password it doesn't complain. Alas in any event the error is still occurring however.

Comment: The certificate you use has to be trusted on server side. And the server certificate has to be trusted by you. Please check through a browser if it is trusted. Open IE type readURL. Server should prompt you to select a certificate. When you select the certificate (that was in p12) see what happens. Any red url bar? any red link in content area?

Comment: I've pasted the (https) url into ie11 and though I don't get asked to select a certificate it connects, I've got the padlock, no red url bar, and I've got some simple text relating to the service I called (just the name of the resource).

Comment: @Robert I know this is old, but as per your comment, the missing password was the answer. If you want to post that as an answer you can have the points...

Comment: =) Will do. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- re-posting comment as answer --

The password is required for this to work.

It is created at the same time as the `.p12` file.